# Make div stay inside the view

Tags: javascript, html, css, web

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="videoPop">
        <div class="point"></div>
        <iframe width="440" height="245"
            src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/fj984wXo3O8?autoplay=1&controls=0&disablekb=1&modestbranding=1&rel=0&loop=1"
            frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope">
        </iframe>
    </div>
    <script>
        window.onload = function () {
            var bsDiv = document.querySelector(".videoPop");
            var x, y;
            window.addEventListener("mousemove", function (event) {
                x = event.clientX;//-217
                y = event.clientY - 165;//-280
                if (typeof x !== "undefined") {
                    bsDiv.style.left = x + "px";
                    bsDiv.style.top = y + "px";
                }
            }, false);
        }
    </script>
    <style>
        .videoPop {
            background-color: #3b3b3b;
            border-radius: 0px;
            position: fixed;
            border-radius: 10px;
            width: 440px;
            height: 245px;
            z-index: 200;
            border: 5px solid #3b3b3b;
            left: 50%;
            top: 50%;
            transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
        }

        .videoPop:after {
            content: '';
            position: absolute;
            top: 100%;
            left: 55%;
            margin-left: -55px;
            width: 0;
            height: 0;
            border-top: solid 30px #3b3b3b;
            border-left: solid 30px transparent;
            border-right: solid 30px transparent;

        }


        .videoPopLoading {
            position: absolute;
            left: 50%;
            top: 50%;
            transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
            width: 50px;
        }

        iframe {
            border-radius: 5px;
        }
    </style>
</body>

</html>
```

The div with the youtube video follows the cursor around while playing the video. But I don't want the video to go over thw windows innerHeight and innerWidth. I want it to maybe stick without going outside but still follow the cursor untill it has to go outside.

*Also with pure JS no JQuery or other libraries*

[image: As you see in this image, the div goes over the innerWidth (wall) I don't want it to]

Comment: You have to check if the mouse position is too close to the screen's bounds to display the popup centered at the current mouse position and if that's the case simply move the popup over until it fits on the screen.

Comment: Then it's just basic math calculations based on the popups width and height, the current mouse position and the window.screen`s height and width.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can calculate the max/min x and y values like this:

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var bsDiv = document.querySelector(".videoPop");
  const divWidth = bsDiv.clientWidth;
  const divHeight = bsDiv.clientHeight;
  const windowWidth = window.innerWidth;
  const windowHeight = window.innerHeight;
  var x, y;
  window.addEventListener("mousemove", function(event) {
    x = Math.max(event.clientX, divWidth / 2); //-217
    y = Math.max(event.clientY - 165, divHeight / 2); //-280
    x = Math.min(x, windowWidth - divWidth / 2);
    y = Math.min(y, windowHeight - divHeight / 2);
    if (typeof x !== "undefined") {
      bsDiv.style.left = x + "px";
      bsDiv.style.top = y + "px";
    }
  }, false);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Title</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="videoPop">
    <div class="point"></div>
    <iframe width="440" height="245" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/fj984wXo3O8?autoplay=1&controls=0&disablekb=1&modestbranding=1&rel=0&loop=1" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope">
        </iframe>
  </div>
  <style>
    .videoPop {
      background-color: #3b3b3b;
      border-radius: 0px;
      position: fixed;
      border-radius: 10px;
      width: 440px;
      height: 245px;
      z-index: 200;
      border: 5px solid #3b3b3b;
      left: 50%;
      top: 50%;
      transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    }
    
    .videoPop:after {
      content: '';
      position: absolute;
      top: 100%;
      left: 55%;
      margin-left: -55px;
      width: 0;
      height: 0;
      border-top: solid 30px #3b3b3b;
      border-left: solid 30px transparent;
      border-right: solid 30px transparent;
    }
    
    .videoPopLoading {
      position: absolute;
      left: 50%;
      top: 50%;
      transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
      width: 50px;
    }
    
    iframe {
      border-radius: 5px;
    }
  </style>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

changed

```
if (typeof x !== "undefined")
```

to

```
if (typeof x !== "undefined" && x -225 > 0 && y -127 > 0 && x < window.innerWidth -225 && y < window.innerHeight -127)
```

complete code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="videoPop">
        <div class="point"></div>
        <iframe width="440" height="245"
            src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/fj984wXo3O8?autoplay=1&controls=0&disablekb=1&modestbranding=1&rel=0&loop=1"
            frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope">
        </iframe>
    </div>
    <script>
        window.onload = function () {
            var bsDiv = document.querySelector(".videoPop");
            var x, y;
            window.addEventListener("mousemove", function (event) {
                x = event.clientX;//-217
                y = event.clientY - 165;//-280
                if (typeof x !== "undefined" && x -225 > 0 && y -127 > 0 && x < window.innerWidth -225 && y < window.innerHeight -127) {

                    bsDiv.style.left = x + "px";
                    bsDiv.style.top = y + "px";
                }
            }, false);
        }
    </script>
    <style>
        .videoPop {
            background-color: #3b3b3b;
            border-radius: 0px;
            position: fixed;
            border-radius: 10px;
            width: 440px;
            height: 245px;
            z-index: 200;
            border: 5px solid #3b3b3b;
            left: 50%;
            top: 50%;
            transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
        }

        .videoPop:after {
            content: '';
            position: absolute;
            top: 100%;
            left: 55%;
            margin-left: -55px;
            width: 0;
            height: 0;
            border-top: solid 30px #3b3b3b;
            border-left: solid 30px transparent;
            border-right: solid 30px transparent;

        }


        .videoPopLoading {
            position: absolute;
            left: 50%;
            top: 50%;
            transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
            width: 50px;
        }

        iframe {
            border-radius: 5px;
        }
    </style>
</body>

</html>
```